# Realm - Migration error

Tags: android, realm

Error: Realm on disc is newer than the one specified: v1 vs. v0

I have tried to add migration code for my project. I see the following error but not sure how to resolve it. I noticed the documentation needs to be updated for RealmMigration. Also I don't want to delete my data, I need to keep it stored. I may not be setting this up right but I was trying to follow the documentation which to me is a bit confusing for migration. Here is my code:

```
    visnetawrap.realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(visnetawrap.realmConfiguration);

    try {
        Realm tempRealmThread = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        tempRealmThread.close();
    }
    catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) {
        Realm.migrateRealm(visnetawrap.realmConfiguration, new RealmMigration() {
            @Override
            public long execute(Realm realm, long l) {
                return 1;
            }
        });
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(visnetawrap.realmConfiguration);
        Log.d("RealmMigration", "Schema has been upgraded.");
    }
```

Comment: You need reflect your changes in the migration. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java Check this example, hope it helps.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I was missing the part where I had to make the changes after migration, I thought it did it automatically! If you want to leave that as an answer I will be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reflect your changes in the migration. Check this [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java), hope it helps.

Comment: I uninstall the application and i get the same error... why?